# How to use python with snort?

Tags: python, machine-learning, snort, ids

I need snort to check incoming traffic for malicious activity but using my machine learning model. I want to use python but I do not know how to do it. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What have you already tried? What went wrong?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply as I mentioned I don't know how I can really do it. How I can invoke python scripts while monitoring packets.

Answer (score 0):

As an option to get started, you can use such Bash script. If the number of snort alerts has increased, it runs your Python script.
(P.S. I did not check the syntax, maybe I need to tweak it a little)

```
#!/bin/bash
alertsOldNumber=0
while true
do
    # save the number of alerts
    alertsNewNumber=$(wc -l /var/log/snort/your_log_file.log | awk -F" " '{print $1}'
    if [[ "$alertsNewNumber" -gt "$alertsOldNumber" ]]
    then
        ./your_python_script.py # do what you want
    fi
    let alertsOldNumber = alertsNewNumber
    sleep 5 # save your resources
done
```